# Strange output of Kriging standard deviation

Tags: kriging, surfer

For my thesis I am interpolating some 4000 boreholepoints via Kriging to try and visualize a geological layer under the ground level. Since I know there is a strong trend in my data (SW-NE slope) I read that using a lineair detrend can be useful to get more detail in the result. I wanted to compare the results of applying a detrend and not applying one. And indeed, the detrended gives a more useful semi-variogram and shows more detail (whether this is useful for my case is still the question). 
However, I also want to compare both standard deviation outputs, to view where the interpolation isn't working as well. For the detrend outpout it shows a clear map. But on the no-detrend one gives a rather strange output. [image]

The two upper maps are the Kriging output and the two below are the standard deviations. Can someone perhaps clarify this output and why it has these holes in it?

Comment: I think -- and this is a guess -- that all of the no-data cells in the second example are being given a value of "something" in your computation such that the standard deviation takes "0 - XValue" at those locations. In the original one, it's working better, but you still see some values where you shouldn't have any. I would perhaps blank to the extents of this map, or something along those lines. Alternatively, make sure how "no-data" is being treated in these. I know filtering can also cause problems in these cases.